# On HTC Desire with onKeyDown and KEYCODE_SEARCH key showed keyboard disappears immediately after it is showed

Tags: android

I have a HTC Desire phone and want to show set focus to input field and show keyboard when user taps hard search [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kppV6.jpg). Keyboard disappears immediately after it is showed on screen.

I have overridden `onKeyDown` with this code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event) {

    if (key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
        EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.list_search_input);
        input.setText(null);

        input.requestFocus();


        // show keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        inputManager.showSoftInput(input, 0);
     }

     return super.onKeyDown(key, event);
 }
```

Waiting for some ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
return super.onKeyDown(key, event);
```

with this:

```
return true;
```

I think that it's because you are letting the default (`super.onKeyDown(key, event);`) event handler to be executed.

Comment: @KristapsGrinbergs Then set this answer as "Accepted answer"! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering how you can compile this! You have a public boolen but you have no return value... try "return super.onKeyDown(key, event);" at the end of the function!

Comment: what android version do you use? could it be the the "rest" of your code does something bad to the keyboard? may try to use SHOW_FORCED or SHOW_IMPLICIT as the second parameter for showSoftInput(View, int)

Comment: I have 2.3.3. It happens the same with blank project and one EditField. Something closes that keyboard, but what? :/

Comment: Here is my code with blank project where I have this issue: https://github.com/fassko/TextFieldFocusKeyboardHTC